# How to compare 2 files word by word and storing the different words in result output file

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose there are two files:

File1.txt

```
My name is Anamika.
```

File2.txt

```
My name is Anamitra.
```

I want result file storing:

Result.txt

```
Anamika                
Anamitra
```

I use putty so can't use wdiff, any other alternative.

Comment: For your examples, please use a formatting that clearly shows the line breaks.

Comment: you can use `wdiff` or `git's` word-diff function.

Comment: Wdiff i can't use, that command is not supported in putty

Comment: Irrelevant.  Putty does not control what commands you can or not use.  The system does.  Or your PATH variable is not set for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not my greatest script, but it works.  Other might come up with something more elegant.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 2 ]
then
    echo "Arguments: file1 file2"
    exit 1
fi

file1=$1
file2=$2

# Do this for both files
for F in $file1 $file2
do
    if [ ! -f $F ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: $F does not exist."
        exit 2
    else
        # Create a temporary file with every word from the file
        for w in $(cat $F)
        do
            echo $w >> ${F}.tmp
        done
    fi
done

# Compare the temporary files, since they are now 1 word per line
# The egrep keeps only the lines diff starts with > or <
# The awk keeps only the word (i.e. removes < or >)
# The sed removes any character that is not alphanumeric.
#         Removes a . at the end for example
diff ${file1}.tmp ${file2}.tmp | egrep -E "<|>" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' > Result.txt

# Cleanup!
rm -f ${file1}.tmp ${file2}.tmp
```

This uses a trick with the `for` loop.  If you use a `for` to loop on a file, it will loop on each word.  NOT each line like beginners in bash tend to believe.  Here it is actually a nice thing to know, since it transforms the files into 1 word per line.

Ex: file content == `This is a sentence.`
    After the `for` loop is done, the temporary file will contain:

```
This
is
a
sentence.
```

Then it is trivial to run `diff` on the files.
One last detail, your sample output did not include a `.` at the end, hence the `sed` command to keep only alphanumeric charactes.

Comment: Great, I would appreciate it if you could accept the answer (the check mark on the left of the answer).